# Bokeh, multi_line: how to select several lines with the box select?

Tags: python, bokeh, selection

I have a Bokeh plot created with the multi_line glyph. I can select a single line with the tap tool or multiple lines with the TapTool+Shift. Is there a way to select several lines at ones with the BoxSelectTool (like on the pic)? The density of the points along each line is quite high, so it's okay if selection works only when 1+ points of a line are inside the box selection area.
I'm looking for a stand-alone solution without a Python server. Writing of some CustomJS code is fine.

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import column
import numpy as np

output_file('tst.html', mode="inline")
n = 8
t = np.linspace(0., 10., 80)
data = ColumnDataSource(dict(xx=[t for cnt in range(n)],
                             yy=[(10 + cnt/2*(-1)**cnt)*np.sin(t + cnt/3) for cnt in range(n)],
                             zz=[(10 - cnt/2*(-1)**cnt)*np.cos(t) for cnt in range(n)]))

f1 = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=300, tools='tap,box_select,reset')
f2 = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=300)
f1.multi_line(xs='xx', ys='yy', source=data)
f2.multi_line(xs='xx', ys='zz', source=data)

save(column(f1, f2))
```

[Plot sample with the box selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8YO0.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not built-in, at least not in Bokeh 2.0.2. The `MultiLine` glyph defines only `_hit_point` (used by the tap, hover, and edit tools) and `_hit_span` (used by the hover tool) methods. For the box select tool to work, there needs to be a `_hit_rect` method defined. It's not that hard to do it yourself, but you will have to create a custom Bokeh model and write some TypeScript for it.

With that being said, please feel free to create a feature request on Bokeh's GitHub!